# How do I pass a specific id to an MVC controller action from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

My html button is in last line

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i].ProductId && data[i].Name && data[i].ShortDescription && data[i].MediumImage && data[i].Price && data[i].IconImage) {
        //alert(data)
        //alert(Photoq);
        //<img id="imgAd" src="/Images/HomeImages/1.jpg" width="181px" height="215px" alt="img">
        var Photo = "<img id='imgAd' src='" + Photoq + "' width='100px' height='100px' alt='img'/>";
        //alert(Photo);
        txt += '<tr><td><div id ="result1" ><div>' + Photo + '</div> <div ><div>' 
        + '<div id="hello">' + data[i].ProductId + '</div>' + "</br> Name- " 
        + data[i].Name + "</br> Description " 
        + data[i].ShortDescription + ", </br>" 
        + data[i].Price + '<div id="cartremove"><input id="Btnremove" type="submit" value="Remove" /></div>' + "</br>";
    }
}
```

And my jquery code is

```
 $(document).on('click', "#cartremove", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     debugger;
     $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")');
 });
```

My controller action is

```
public ActionResult Deletecart(int id)
    {
        return view();
    }
```

I want to pass a specific id to the controller action, but my jquery `$.getjson` is not connecting to the action controller.  How can I make it work?

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: can u plz show it in code?

Comment: see for  what indentation [this link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?608301-What-is-indenting-and-why-should-I-do-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Deletecart` expects parameter `id` but you’re not passing anything and you’re not doing anything with the returned html

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")', { id: someValue }, function(data) { 
  // do something with the html that as returned 
});
```

Suggest also that you change

```
<input id="Btnremove" type="submit" value="Remove" />
```

to

```
<button class="Btnremove" type="button">Remove</button>
```

in which case you can remove `e.preventDefault()` since its not submitting, and you’re not duplicating ID's