# I want to pass my id to controller action from my jquery json code in my mvc4 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

My id is here

```
var k = $(this).data[i].ProductId;
```

my jquery code is

```
 $(document).on('click', ".Btnremove", function (event) {
   alert('feo')
   $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")',
     { id: }, location.reload(true), function (data) {
   });
});
```

In above code 4th line i have `{id: }`. How do I pass that `k` value to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuance of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437100/i-want-to-pass-specific-id-to-the-controller-actionbut-my-jquery-getjson-is-n/26437264#26437264), You should add your product id to button using custom `data-*` prefixed attribute. like

```
'<input class="Btnremove" data-id="' + data[i].ProductId +  '"/>'
```

Which can be fetched using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like `$(this).data('id')`

*Code*

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i].ProductId && data[i].Name && data[i].ShortDescription && data[i].MediumImage && data[i].Price && data[i].IconImage) {
         txt += ....
        + '<div class="cartremove"><input class="Btnremove" type="submit" value="Remove" data-id="' + data[i].ProductId +  '"/></div>' + "</br>";
    }
}
 $(document).on('click', ".Btnremove", function(event) {
     $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")', {
         id: $(this).data('id')
     }, function(data) {
         location.reload(true)
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use query string that can makes you easy with understanding

$(document).on('click', ".Btnremove", function (event) {

alert('feo')

$.getJSON("@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")"+"?id='value'",

```
  location.reload(true), function (data) {
```

});
});